# how to integrate Facebook-ios-sdk to SenTestCase class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, unit-testing

How to integrate facebook-ios-sdk into Targets senTesting

I created a project let it be DemoProject and also integrated the facebook-ios-sdk run the project every thing is working fine. now i am trying to write test case for my DemoProject
where i need to integrate Facebook-ios-sdk to DemoProjectTest.  how to configure facebook-ios-sdk to DemoProjectTest Target.  so i can able to create object for the Facebook.

I am unable to include `#import "facebook-ios-sdk/Facebook.h"` inside my class for the DemoProjectTest Target for class `FacebookTest.h.`  If i do import the `Facebook.h` then i can able to create the object for the Facebook.

Is it possible to integrate Facebook-ios-sdk into DemoProjectTest Target?

@All any one advice me for scenario.